# Adding an alias for git commit so that no quotes are needed

Tags: linux, git, zsh, alias

In git, when I commit a change I use:

```
git commit -m "my commit message"
```

I find this time consuming to type out each time, especially since I have a habit of making many small commits over time

I want an alias that makes this easier, for example

```
gm commit message
```

I don't like having to type the quotes before and after my commit message, and "gm" is a lot quicker than "git commit -m"

what is the best way to make this alias in my .zshrc file?

Comment: Realistically, if these are commits you'll publish anywhere or keep as history, you should omit the `-m "message"` and type a more complete description in the editor; if they're just checkpoints that you'll squash before publishing/merging, `-mwip` is fine (no quotes needed for a single word).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **zsh**:

```
setopt interactive_comments
preexec(){ _lc=$1; }
alias gm='git commit -m "${_lc#gm }" #'
```

then:

```
gm ** you can use ", ) or any other char's in the commit message
```

Notice that other of your aliases, etc. may use the `preexec` function; you may have to modify it instead of just overriding it.

---

In **bash** or **ksh93**, there's no `preexec`, but you can get the current command from the history:

```
alias gm='_lc=$(fc -nl -0); git commit -m "${_lc#*gm }" #'
```

Also, bash and ksh93 recognize comments by default in interactive scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
gm() { git commit -m "$*" }
```

```
gm this works
gm but you need to quote special chars\!
```

Comment: I get the following error: "defining function based on alias gm'" & "parse error near ()'"

Comment: @Hitomi90 That's because you already have an alias defined; Use `unalias gm` before defining the function. You can also use `function gm() { git commit -m "$*" }` which will not show you an error, but the defined function will be shadowed by the alias.