# In C, how to receive the argument "q w; e r' (quotes included) from the command line?

Tags: c

the command line will be like

`./a.out "q w; e r'`

I have a function receiving string as argument, so I used

`function_name(argv[1]);`

it turns out that this won't work when my input contains whitespace, quotes, and semicolons, etc. So, I'm considering to save the command line input as a string variable and call the function using this variable.

Comment: If you want to pass the string `"q w; e r'`, you could do so with `./a.out '"q w; e r'"'"`  or `./a.out '"q w; e r'\'`

Comment: The issue is getting the shell to accept the arguments, and that comes down to understanding how to use your shell to properly pass the arguments to the program in the form it wants them. You need to tell the shell that the string, though it contains spaces, is a single argument.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you want to know: How to quote the argument string in your shell to get it as `argv[1]`? Or how to reconstruct the whole string in your C program when the shell has split it into separate arguments? Please also tell us what operating system and shell you use.

Comment: @Bodo it's impossible to reconstruct an original argument after the shell has processed it, so the latter is certainly not a good question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

For most shells you need to surround text with quotes if there's spaces, and escape quotes if they conflict with the surrounding quotes. In other words:

```sh
./a.out "\"q w; e r'"
```

Comment: @user414777 Anyone still using `csh` is in for a world of hurt anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much and how strange your input is, you may want to consider reading it from a file. The processing of arguments, especially special characters, is very dependent on the environment. The command line that allows you to run the code you want is going to be different between Windows and the various Unix-like shells. Passing a file name is fairly standard, however, and your file can contain arbitrary bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with C, but with the shell or other interface you start your program from.

In most **Unix shells** you can escape a command line argument by turning each embedded single quote (`'`) into `'\''`, and enclosing the whole string in single quotes:

```
./a.out '"q w; e r'\'     # here you can simplify the terminating '\''' to '\'
./a.out 'Omar m'\''a tuer'
```

If your shell is **bash** you escape the quoting hell by adapting this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289920/14223576) to create a `q cmd ...` alias which would call `cmd` with the rest of the command line passed as its *single* argument:

```
alias q='_l=$(fc -nl -0); _l=${_l#*q }; "${_l%% *}" "${_l#* }" #'
```

then use as:

```
q ./a.out "q w; e r'
```

Example:

```
$ ./x.out(){ printf "{%s}\n" "$@"; }
$ q ./x.out "q w; e r'
{"q w; e r'}
```